Type inference problem with array of generic config objects with different inner types that depend on other inner property
I'm trying to create a generic function that will create some pretty common effects, so I'll be able to pass only the config and it will create the effect.
Here are some imports from NgRx:
import { ActionCreator } from '@ngrx/store';
import { createActionGroup, props } from '@ngrx/store';


and one ActionGroup for testing purposes:
export const featureActions = createActionGroup({
  source: 'MyGroup',
  events: {
    'Update Entity': props<{ data: { updateName: string } }>(),
    'Delete Entity': props<{ data: { deleteName: string } }>(),
  },
});


So to achieve that I've created a config file that accepts a ngrx action (ActionCreator) and one mapping function.
export type Config<AC extends ActionCreator> = {
  action: AC;
  mapping: (data: ReturnType<AC>) => string;
};

The factory function itself accepts the array of these configs:
export function createMyEffects<AC extends ActionCreator>(
  effects: Config<AC>[]
) {
  // doing nothing, I guess it is not relevant
  console.log(effects);
}

The issue happens on function call:
createMyEffects([
  {
    action: featureActions.updateEntity,
    mapping: (updateData) => updateData.data.updateName, // place #2
  },
  {
    // Issue is that it thinks that this action should be the same as the first
    action: featureActions.deleteEntity, // the place #1
    mapping: (deleteData) => deleteData.data.deleteName, // place #3
  },
]);

So with my function declaration TS throws me at place #1 that typeof FeatureAtions.deleteEntity isn't assignable to typeof FeatureAtions.updateEntity.
So I changed it to
export function createMyEffects<AC extends ActionCreator[]>(
  effects: Config<AC[number]>[],
)

and in this case, there are no errors, but now I'm losing the type inference at places #2 and #3. deleteData and updateData args infer type Object instead of ReturnType< FeatureAtions.deleteEntity> and ReturnType<FeatureAtions.updateEntity> corresponding.
How could I ensure the type inference in this case?
UPD:
Here is stackblits link with env

Is this a [mre]? Are FeatureAtions, ActionCreator, and and ToastEffectConfig private types or do they get exported by angular/ngrx? If they're private, please [edit] the question to declare them (or even better, remove them and replace with native TS). If they're from technology the question depends on, please import them explicitly in the example. The goal is that we can copy and paste your code into our own IDEs and immediately see your issue and get to work on it.

Thanks for the updates but there's still a bunch missing. Please try out your own code example in a standalone IDE and fix any typos or inconsistencies or missing things you're not asking about. (e.g., data? Toast? updateName? other stuff too?)

I see three errors where you are mentioning three errors, but those errors are all typos. You're writing actions instead of action, and data instead of updateData and deleteData. And updateName and deleteName appear nowhere else in the code. When I asked you to try out your own code in a standalone IDE... did you do that?  I'm really trying to help but it's very difficult when I have to debug my way to get to the problem.

@jcalz I've added the link to stackblitz, I hope it helps to reproduce the challenge.

But the code needs to be here as plaintext. I don't have the rights to copy code from your stackblitz into here, could you please [edit] to do that?  And even in that stackblitz I see actionMapping where mapping is expected? I'm not sure how else to ask that you fix your typos before calling others' attention to the code. All it does is slow people down and force them to deal with issues you're not even trying to ask about. Could you please edit the code in here as plain text and quadruple check it to make sure that there are no typos?

(see prev comment.) Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer, and if you give me permission, I'll also [edit] your question code to provide the relevant [mre] with no typos or missing declarations. If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz , yes, thanks your approach meets what I was looking for. Sorry for the typos, and definitely you are welcome to edit my question.

Thanks! I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

@jcalz, The only thing left is that even your example doesn't infer the types on typescript v5.2.2.  Do you have any idea why and is there a way to deal with it on v5.2.2 or the only way is to go for v5.4.5?

I don't know, that really seems out of scope. I don't see anything in the question that specifies a particular version of TypeScript.  I'm going to wait and not write an answer here until I know whether or not that matters enough for you to [edit] the question to specify TS5.2. Let me know how to proceed.

I had no idea that the version could be related to the issue. I will accept your answer because regardless of the version, your code works and my isn't. It would be nice in case you have any ideas regarding how I could make it with v5.2.2.

It certainly seems like something changed in TS5.4 to make it start working, but the release notes for TS5.4 don't mention it, meaning I'd need to start digging to see exactly which commit changed things and see what it's related to before I could even venture a guess as to how to get it working in prior versions. I don't think I can commit to spending that kind of time looking at it, at least not right now.

Nah, nah. Thank you so much, it's totally fine.

Note that the relevant change is discussed here. If you must use TS5.2, I'd suggest using a rest param instead of an array input, as shown in this playground link. I will probably not put any of that in my answer.

Awesome. Thanks for your effort. Will wait for your answer to mark the question resolved.

If you want each element of your effects array input to have its own type argument to Config<>, then you will need to make the function generic in a tuple type of those type arguments, and make effects a mapped tuple type:
function createMyEffects<AC extends ActionCreator[]>(
    effects: { [I in keyof AC]: Config<AC[I]> }
) {
    console.log(effects);
}

This will then work as desired, at least for TypeScript 5.4 and above:
createMyEffects([
    {
        action: featureActions.updateEntity,
        mapping: (updateData) => updateData.data.updateName,
    },
    {
        action: featureActions.deleteEntity,
        mapping: (deleteData) => deleteData.data.deleteName,
    },
]);

Unfortunately before TypeScript 5.4 this wouldn't work properly... TypeScript has the ability to infer from mapped types, but when the function input is an array literal this didn't work right.  It was fixed in microsoft/TypeScript#56555.
Playground link to code
